# How to Stop Looping when the input is null (for int) Java

Tags: java, null, int

i just made my own program for stop loop when the input is `null`, but this program can only succeed with String.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = " ";
while(true) {
    name = scan.nextLine();
    if(name.equals("")) {
       break;
    }
}
```

so, if you didn't put anything on the `String name` you just click enter on your keyboard than the loop gonna be stop.

but when you try to change the String to int, there is one problem that you will get.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int name = " ";
while(true) {
    name = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    if(name....) {
       break;
    }
}
```

what must be fill in `if` ?

Comment: An `int` can never be `null`

Comment: You are initializing int name = "  "; it is illegal ...

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one problem here. You can't initialise int name = " "; int has to have a numerical value ranging from negative 2³¹ to positive 2³¹-1, but you cant set the value to null as it is a primitive datatype.

Whenever you use scan.nextInt(); the program won't continue until you enter a number. If you want to break a loop by just clicking on the enter button, try this:-

```
...
int name=0;
while(true) {
    try {
        name = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Since name can't hold a null value, it will throw an Exception. The program will catch that Exception and break out from the loop.

If you don't know "Exception Handling", I suggest you to look up the internet and learn it because it's a very useful block to use in programs.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `scan.nextInt()`

This scans the next token of the input as an `int`

Answer (score 0):

There is no **must** here.

That is the whole point: you are the one defining what should happen.

The first thing to understand is the potential range of int values. We are talking about positive and negative numbers here.

So *one* option could be to stop on 0. Or on -1.

But that is the thing: as soon as you turn away from strings (which can be null, empty, or contain all kinds of information) to something that is more specific, you lose some degrees of freedom.

Thus, the real answer is: there is no "generic" answer here. If you insist on turning the user input into an int value, then you are confined to the range of possible int values. And unless you define some rule such as "any negative numbers means *stop*", you don't have any way to know when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your inputs as strings even if they are numerical values. That means, your first block of code will work if you only need to find the empty value after a stream of inputs(no matter what they are: abc or 123).